# why visual studio 2019 installer not work?

Tags: visual-studio

I tried to install visual studio 2019, but when i ran visual studio installer, after seconds, this image appeared and after that, disappeared and nothing happened. when i tried again i got that again.

OS is up to date!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4w2H.png)

Comment: Visual Studio does not take seconds to install. Your installation file is probably corrupted.

Comment: @harrymc i tested two file, but i got same result. in previous OS i installed visual without problem

Comment: Did you check if any firewall is blocking connections to that vs installer?

Comment: @Biswapriyo i turned off defender and firewall, but no change :((